# Custom WP_List_Table: How to create an unapproved row?

Tags: wp-list-table

In this [Example](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/), let's assume every item had the attribute `$item['approved']` with values Zero unapproved and One for approved.

How can I get the rows of the "unapproved books" to be yellow?

(well, it's not about the yellow, but about the WP standard compliant procedure of marking rows as unapproved)

Comment: I have trouble following how row actions (controls) connect to row presentation (styling) in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the yellow comes from

```
<tr class="unapproved">
```

and this is, in crass contrast to what the usual `WP_List_Table` introduction might suggest, not an automatism, but generated very verbatim:

See e.g. `single_row()` in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php`:

```
function single_row( $a_comment ) {
                global $post, $comment;

                $comment = $a_comment;
                $the_comment_class = join( ' ', get_comment_class( wp_get_comment_status( $comment->comment_ID ) ) );

                $post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );

                $this->user_can = current_user_can( 'edit_comment', $comment->comment_ID );

                echo "<tr id='comment-$comment->comment_ID' class='$the_comment_class'>";
                echo $this->single_row_columns( $comment );
                echo "</tr>\n";
        }
```

which overrides the standard method inherited from `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php`